# Python scheduler on top of a scheduler

Tags: python, macos, schedule

I have a function that is scheduled every Monday at 9:00am.

After that schedule run I need to repeat the function each hour.

Here is my code:

```
import schedule
import time

def main_job():
    print('Hello World')

def schech():
    schedule.every().minute.do(main_job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


schedule.every().day.at("17:46").do(schech)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Error I am getting:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while loop in your schech() function.

```
import schedule
import time

def main_job():
    print('Hello World')

def schech():
    main_job()
    schedule.every(60).minutes.do(main_job)

schedule.every().day.at("9:00").do(schech)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```